# css stye just for selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add style for a selected element, for example:

I have `bootstrap.css`

and I have

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></head>
<body>
<div id='a' class ='container'></div>
<div id='b' class ='container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible add `bootstrap.css` style only for `#a` element with jQuery or something else?

Comment: remove the class `container` from `#b`

Comment: When you import a stylesheet, the style is added to the whole document. It makes more sense to copy the styles that you require for the element than add the entire stylesheet for a single element.

Comment: But you can override the property with your own properties

Comment: i mean bootstrap style only affect for #a

Comment: Agree with @MrBones, I will suggest you to `cut` required code from `bootstrap.css` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using SASS Inheritance.

Please refer below code :

```
'#a {
     @import url(bootstrap.css);
}'
```

This will render you bootstrap css with "#a" prefix parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can not do so.
After all its a whole html document.
Whichever css you include, It will apply to all elements of page.

One solution is for #b, You need to override the styles, If any that are applied by bootstrap.css

Comment: yes i can override it, but the script above is just example so it's easy to override in my original script there are so much element have to be overrided :(

Comment: As per my knowledge, There is no short cut to do so. You must have to override these elements.

Answer (score -1):

you have bootstrap.css and if you want to assign custom style to specific element..

use...jquery

```js
$("#a").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></head>
<body>
<div id='a' class ='container'>color</div>
<div id='b' class ='container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

if you want to overwrite

```js
$("#a").attr('style', 'text-align: center;color:red;');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></head>
<body>
<div id='a' class ='container'>red</div>
<div id='b' class ='container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And this is helping him in which way?

Comment: Single quotes in html is never a good sign.